# Groovy code gets faster and slower when using "@CompileStatic"

Tags: time, groovy, static-compilation

I have the following snipet of Groovy code

```
class Test 
{
//  @groovy.transform.CompileStatic
    static main(args) 
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        def x = "3967"
        println x ==~ /[0-9]+([1379])$/
        println System.currentTimeMillis()-start
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to test weather *x* is a number ending in 1,3,7,or 9

I'm using the groovy plugin for eclipse, so when i want to run the code I have a few options, I can either run it as a Groovy Script, or as a Java application.  Here are the runtimes.

```
Groovy Script: 93ms
Java Application: 125ms
```

But then when I enable Static compilation, this happens

```
Groovy Script: 0ms
Java Application: 312ms
```

I'm confused,
1. I thought compiling to a Java application was supposed to be faster than running Groovy as a script.
2. Why is it that the Groovy script option gets so much faster with static compilation, and the Java one gets longer?

Comment: Groovy, even as a script, is compiled to bytecode. This must be related to how eclipse handles compilation and execution. Have you done any warm up before running the tests?

Comment: Extending @WillP's comment, mimic `Test.groovy` to `Test.java` and run both of them side by side, possibly with `groovyc` and `javac` respectively.

Comment: Also, consider using `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` for more accurate timing.

Comment: And the level of error in measuring a single call of a single thing right after startup of the JVM is going to be immense